# VBA Loop for specific letters in alphabet

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I would like to loop through the contents of a column in excel using VBA. In each cell there is a word. For words that start with letters 'P-Z' I want to return a '1', otherwise '0'.

e.g.:

```
DOG
CAT
PONY
ZEBRA
```

returns:

```
0
0
1
1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function Starter(s As String) As Integer
    Starter = 0
    If Left(s, 1) Like "[P-Z]" Then Starter = 1
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

**EDIT**

Now that we already have the *function* we can insert a *sub* to use that function:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Starter(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The VBE now looks like:

[image]

Comment: Gary- thank you how do I run the loop solely in VBA and have it place 1/0 in column B?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using **EXCEL FORMULA**.

Using Simple `IF ELSE` condition in EXCEL, it can be achieved.

Check the below formula:

```
=IF(AND(CODE(LEFT(UPPER(TRIM(A1)))) >=80, CODE(LEFT(UPPER(TRIM(A1))))<=90),1,0)
```

Comment: OP wants to return 1 if the first letter of the cell in question is *between* P and Z (inclusive). This will only return 1 if the letter is P *or* Z.

Comment: @Aiken: Formula Updated please Check now.

Comment: Or `=IF(AND(UPPER(A1)>="P",UPPER(A1)<="Z"),1,0)`